# Is Kaspersky deleting my files?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, anti-virus, kaspersky

My coworker has a Windows 7 Professional x64 machine with Kaspersky installed. Lately, Kaspersky has been giving her popups with malware warnings. Today, she informed me that Kaspersky brought up a pop up about something which eventually asked her to restart the computer, which then she did. When she logged into Windows again, all the folders and files in the Documents folder were gone. This is where she kept almost all of her stuff.

Could you please tell me - If Kaspersky deleted her files, is there a way to know that? Does Kaspersky keep a log of deleted files? Is there any way those files could be retrieved? Please help, we are really in a spot of bother due to loss of that data.

I suppose system restore isn't going to help me. Please correct me if I am wrong.

PS : I don't know that Kaspersky itself deleted the files. All I know is that Kaspersky gave a malware warning, then asked for reboot, and the files went missing thereafter.

Comment: Are you certain it was Kaspersky that deleted the files? Or was it the malware Kaspersky was warning about masquerading as Kaspersky?

Comment: @Tyson No, I am not sure that Kaspersky proper was the one that deleted the files.

Comment: If Kaspersky removed files, it's because they were infected. They will have been copied to quarantine, but it is not recommended to recover them from there: use a back-up instead.

Comment: @AFH is it always the case the Kaspersky quarantines infected files? It is noteworthy that stuff in quarantine is still retrievable. Does Kaspersky ever delete stuff irretrievably?

Comment: There may be settings for that: I use a home edition, which will probably differ from a work-place version, so my settings options won't be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. For some reason, the `Documents` shortcut in the Windows Explorer left hand side pane was pointing to a wrong folder, some weird location in `system 32`. The files were where they were before in `C:\\Users\\...`. Maybe the malware corrupted what location `Documents` from Windows Explorer left hand pane points to.